# duplicate element in hashset ( after implementing comparator /compare method correctly )

Tags: java, compare, comparator, duplicates, treeset

I'm currently writing a program which reads lines from a file and create tokens. The tokens are then saved in treeset. I don't want any duplicates in the set, so I've implemented Comparator with correct compare method. But still I'm not able to figure out why one element is repeated in the treeset.

Input file :  (13 lines)

```
VEG,SMALL,Corn,MOZZARELLA 
VEG,LARGE,Capsicum,CHEDDAR 
VEG,MEDIUM,Olives,COTTAGE 
VEG,MEDIUM,Garlic,MOZZARELLA 
VEG,LARGE,Peppers,CHEDDAR     
NONVEG,MEDIUM,Beef,CHEDDAR  
NONVEG,LARGE,Chicken,COTTAGE  
NONVEG,SMALL,Pork,MOZZARELLA  
NONVEG,LARGE,Mutton,CHEDDAR    
NONVEG,SMALL,Mutton,MOZZARELLA 
VEG,SMALL,Corn,MOZZARELLA
NONVEG,MEDIUM,Beef,CHEDDAR 
NONVEG,SMALL,Mutton,MOZZARELLA
```

My Code :

```
public Set<Pizza> populateData(String FileName) {

    Set<Pizza> set = new TreeSet(new Comparator<Pizza>(){

        @Override
        public int compare(Pizza o1, Pizza o2) {

            if(o1.getPizzType().compareTo(o2.getPizzType())==0)
            {
                if(o1.getCheeseType().compareTo(o2.getCheeseType())==0)
                {
                    if(o1.getSize().compareTo(o2.getSize())==0)
                    {
                        if(o1.getTopping().compareTo(o2.getTopping())==0)
                        {
                            return 0;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return 54;
        }


    });


    File file = new File(FileName);
    Scanner scanner=null;

    try {
        scanner=new Scanner(new FileInputStream(file));
        Pizza pizza=null;

        while(scanner.hasNext())
        {
            String line=scanner.nextLine();
            String words[]=new String[4];
            words=line.split(",");

            pizza=new Pizza();

            if(words[0].trim().length()>0)
            {
                pt=PizzaType.valueOf(words[0].trim());
                pizza.setPizzType(PizzaType.valueOf(words[0].trim()));
            }
            if(words[1].trim().length()>0)
            {
                sz=(Size.valueOf(words[1].trim()));
                pizza.setSize(Size.valueOf(words[1].trim()));
            }
            if(words[2].trim().length()>0)
            {
                tp=(words[2].trim());
                pizza.setTopping(words[2].trim());
            }
            if(words[3].trim().length()>0)
            {
                ct=(CheeseType.valueOf(words[3].trim()));
                pizza.setCheeseType(CheeseType.valueOf(words[3].trim()));
            }


            set.add(pizza);

        }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return set;
}
```

(output printed along with string length and hashcode)

Output: (11 lines) {first and last line is duplicate :P}

```
VEG SMALL Corn MOZZARELLA 22  589431969
VEG LARGE Capsicum CHEDDAR 23  1252169911
VEG MEDIUM Olives COTTAGE 22  2101973421
VEG MEDIUM Garlic MOZZARELLA 25  685325104
VEG LARGE Peppers CHEDDAR 22  460141958
NONVEG MEDIUM Beef CHEDDAR 23  1163157884
NONVEG LARGE Chicken COTTAGE 25  1956725890
NONVEG SMALL Pork MOZZARELLA 25  356573597
NONVEG LARGE Mutton CHEDDAR 24  1735600054
NONVEG SMALL Mutton MOZZARELLA 27  21685669
VEG SMALL Corn MOZZARELLA 22  2133927002
```

Expected Output: (10 lines)

```
VEG SMALL Corn MOZZARELLA  
VEG LARGE Capsicum CHEDDAR
VEG MEDIUM Olives COTTAGE 
VEG MEDIUM Garlic MOZZARELLA
VEG LARGE Peppers CHEDDAR 
NONVEG MEDIUM Beef CHEDDAR 
NONVEG LARGE Chicken COTTAGE
NONVEG SMALL Pork MOZZARELLA
NONVEG LARGE Mutton CHEDDAR 
NONVEG SMALL Mutton MOZZARELLA
```

Comment: Your compare return 0 or 54. How is that correct?

Comment: Have you overridden the `equals` and `hashCode` methods of `Pizza`?

Comment: @UmNyobe Returning anything other than 0 will sort the list (either ascending/descending), right ?

Comment: @RealSkeptic 
No I haven't.
I've tried to override it. But it returns the set with duplicate elements..

Comment: @UmNyobe I tried to return -1 or 1...Still incorrect output :P

Comment: Note: (1) your title says `HashSet`, but you are using `TreeSet`. They are different implementations. `TreeSet` is for things that have an order relation between them (one is "greater" than the other). Since you care about uniqueness rather than order, you should be using `HashSet` and not use a `Comparator`. (2) You *always* have to override the `equals` and `hashCode` when you use your class in a `Set` even if it's not a `HashSet`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Comparator contract](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) requires to return negative if `o1 < o2`, positive if `o1 > o2`, and zero if `o1 == o2`.

Which means  your code need to look like

```
public int compare(Pizza o1, Pizza o2) {

    int compvalue = o1.getPizzType().compareTo(o2.getPizzType());
    if(compvalue == 0)
    {
        compvalue = o1.getCheeseType().compareTo(o2.getCheeseType());
        ...etc..
        if(compvalue == 0)
        ...
    }
    return compvalue;
}
```